# Issues solving Project Euler #4

Tags: java

The problem reads

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
>   made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
>   numbers.

I don't understand. I double checked everything before trying to reverse the number, but after that I don't get anything in the console but 0s.

```
public class E4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int product, rev = 0;

    for (int x = 0, y = 1; x <= 99 && y <= 99;) {
        product = x * y;                            //This for loop multiplies numbers from 0-99 * 1            
        if (x == 99) {                              //Then numbers from 0-99 * 2, and so on, until 99*99
            y++;
            x = 0;
        }
        x++;        

        while (product != 0) {
            rev = rev * 10;                        //This loop should reverse the products and then
            rev = rev + product % 10;              //The if loop should check if it is a palindrome number
            product = product / 10;                //But it doesn't work?

            if (rev == product) {
                System.out.println(rev);
            }

        }

      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Please tell us what you are expecting to get as output.

Comment: It should give me every palindrome number, that comes as a product

Comment: Maybe you need to move the if block out of the while loop.

Comment: Nope. Already tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that should work for you.

```
public class E4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int product = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
                product = x * y;
                int rev = reverseInt(product);
                if (rev == product) {
                    System.out.println(rev);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private static int reverseInt(int product) {
        int rev = 0;
        while (product != 0) {
            rev = rev * 10;
            rev += product % 10;
            product = product / 10;
        }
        return rev;
    }
}
```

Part of your problem is that your code always ended up with `product` being 0 at the end (since your while loop changed it and only exited when `product == 0`).  Also, you never reset `rev` to `0`.